# Launching program in Qemu

Tags: testing, ssh, qemu, virtualization

I have a program that should be tested against various arm64 and amd64 kernels. To do so I want to use `qemu-system-[aarch64|x86_64]` with target kernel and manually-builded initramfs which contains testing program, busybox and dropbear (small SSH server). Test script on Host platform will launch Qemu (with SSH port forwarding from Host to Guest), then connects to it with SSH client, will launch test program, and checks exit code. Optionally print stdout/stderr if exit code is not 0.

Only thing that bothers me is SSH connection between Host and Guest system. Is there any other way to launch process in Guest system from Host with ability to check exit code, stdout and stderr?